# Weird behavior when set Array of Strings to HashMap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm tryna add to HashMap Array of Strings but instead of normal Array of String I see only address in memory of String in console.

```
val map = mapOf<String, Array<String>>()
val list = listOf("sport")
val array = list.toTypedArray()
map["key"] to array
```

And Array after this operation converts in smth like this — [Ljava.lang.String;@518ed9b4

But expected to see this kind of behavior:

map["key"] -> array("sport")

What's the problem might be with this sample of code?

Comment: I think you are printing it wrong. Try ```print(Arrays.toString(map["key"]))```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want as output, but I think your map is empty.  If you going to print using @AkshayBhat'AB', you gonna need something like `val map = mapOf("key" to array)`. After this I think you will have [sport].

Comment: This is yet another demonstration of why it's best to use Lists rather than Arrays in Kotlin. Arrays have a few specialised uses (interoperabiilty with old code, varargs, and low-level implementation); but for everything else, lists are much better supported in the standard library, handle generics properly, can be immutable, and usually have proper `toString()` and other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Java/Kotlin don't have a good automatic conversion to strings (technically, their implementation of `toString()`). What you see is your array, but instead of showing the contents, it only says it is an array of strings and shows the memory address.

To show the contents of an array you can use builtin `contentToString()` extension or wrap it into a list:

```kotlin
println(arrayOf("sport").contentToString())
println(arrayOf("sport").asList())
```

BTW, I believe there is a mistake in your example. `map["key"] to array` doesn't do anything, it should be probably `map["key"] = array`. Also, map in your example is read-only, you can't add items to it. However, as you already got to the point you print an array, I assume your real code is a little different.